# How to detect the default dropdown option vs. selected with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show the value of a dropdown only if it has actually a selected option with selected attribute. Browsers are detecting the first dropdown option by default regardless if it has selected attr or not. So :selected method gives you a result regardless. Is there any way to detect if the selected option actually has the selected attribute?

Answer (score 1):

$( "#optionTagID" ).val(); 
[jQuery docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)
Gives you the value of the selected option. You can check if this is the desired value and then [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the element accordingly.

Comment: If you take out the "selected" in the HTML code @pittofdirk posted then the first option will not be selected by default and in the jQuery action:- $(this).val() will be an empty string, which you can check for.

Answer (score 1):

In your option tags, you can have a property of "selected"

```
<select>
    <option value="">Please select an option</option>
    <option selected value="foobar">foobar</option>
</select>
```

For jQuery you can do this:

```
$("select option").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("selected") == true)
    {
        alert("found the selected option. The value is: " + $(this).val());
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o24g9feo/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The browser is picking the top option by default and browsers identify that as the selected option. The question is how to exclude the result if it doesn't actually have the attribute selected.

Comment: The browser will identify it as the selected option if it has a value associated with it. Make your first option one with an empty value such as:

<option value="">Please select an option</option>